# realizar una consulta con una etiqueta select y poner datos a un ckeditor

Tags: php, javascript

Hola mi problema es el siguiente y es que tengo un cheditor en el que quiero mostrar una columna que esta en la base de datos.

```
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 6%; top: 24%">
         <b>Seleccione una plantilla: </b>
        <select required="required" id="plantilla"  onchange="SelecionPlantilla(this.value)" >
          <option value="">Seleccione una plantilla</option>
          @foreach($plantillas as $plan)

          <option class="last"  id="{{$plan->ID}}" value="{{$plan->ID}}">{{$plan->plantilla}}</option>

          @endforeach
        </select>
       <input type="button" name="Mostrar" id="Mostrar" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"  value="Mostrar">
      </div>

        <div style="position: absolute; left: 10%; top: 29%; ">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <textarea  class="ckeditor" name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                         <p id="plan{{$plan-ID}}" style="display: none;">
                           <p>{{$plan->description}}</p>
                         </p>


                  </textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

por ejemplo esa es la vista con lo que se  muestran los campos en en el select, plantillas es el nombre de la base de datos, y el me muestra los tipos ejemplo el 1 es no hay cambios 2 es hay cambios pero no relevante  3 si existen cambios. cada campo de esos son el ID = 1 ,plantilla = no hay cambios   description = gracias por leer antentamente esto.... lo que quiero es poner la description que se ponga al yo selecionar el 1 o 2 o 3,  y que cambie con el respectivo campo y que se ponga en el checkeditor. que esta.

trate de hacer algo asi pero no funciona no hace nada

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Mostrar').click(function(){
    var id = $('#plantilla').val();
    var token = $(this).data("token");
    $.ajax({
        url : '/clientgroup/text',
        data : { ID : id ,_method: 'POST',_token:token},
        type : 'POST',
        success : function(json) {
          console.log(json)
          if (json.length ==0) {
            swal('Buscamos pero','Encontramos informacion','info');
          }
            json.forEach(function(element) { 
               swal('','','success');  
               $('#idarchivoescondido').show();
               $('#plan'+element[0]).show();

            });
        },
        error : function(xhr, status) {
            swal('Error','Disculpe presentamos algún errro','error');
        }
    });
});
```

y esta es la ruta.

```
Route::post('/clientgroup/text','GroupClientsController@searchText');
```

si alguien me puede ayudar, seria increíble

esto esta en el controlador

```
public function searchText(Request $request)
{
    $query= Plantillas::all();
    $list= array();
    foreach ($query as $file) {
        if (trim($file->ID)) {
            $array = explode(",", $file->ID);
            foreach ($array as $item) {
                if ($item == $request->ID) {
                    $add = array($file->description);
                    $list[] = $add;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return $list;
}
```

Comment: ¿ya has comprobado en la consola si te está regresando datos tu petición `ajax`?, el contenido que quieres establecer dentro del ckeditor, ¿en qué formato está?

Comment: si los comprobé, el formato en el que esta es un array pero no se muestra en el ckeditor

Comment: Si, es un array, pero a lo que me refería es que, ¿es html el contenido dentro de cada casilla del array?

Comment: no se a que te refieres con contenido html, es un texto en las columnas

Comment: es texto, aunque no se a que te refieres con formato html

Comment: Bueno, no importa, ¿en qué parte del código se supone que estás estableciendo el valor para el ckeditor?, para establecer el valor de tu respuesta ajax, debería ser algo como: `CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(valor);` y no logro verlo en tu código.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, eso era lo que me faltaba,  un error mio, muchas gracias ya agregue eso y listo

Comment: Listo, ya la puse como respuesta, marcala como aceptada para que les pueda ser de ayuda a los demás.

Comment: Listo, Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para establecer el valor de tu respuesta ajax en el `CKEDITOR`, debería ser algo como:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(valor);
```